# Convert time in hh:mm:ss AM(PM) format (sql)

Tags: sql

How do I convert time :  ' 8:02:24 AM ' into ' 08:02:24 AM ' so that all the time in a particular column is of fixed length.

I tried using different style values in convert function but couldn't get my desired result.

Comment: Please tag ONLY the relevant DBMS. Oracle, SQL Server and MySQL all handle differently

Comment: what is your source column datatype?

Comment: @RajeshBhat datetime

Comment: If it is datetime field then it will store in hh:mm:ss format. Between which database server are you using?

Comment: @RajeshBhat i want it in a fixed length, if its 8:00:00AM then it should show 08:00:00AM, I am using sql server 2008.

Comment: Here is a third request to specify the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CONVERT function to convert all time value to 24 hours format

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, <your column name>, 108) AS HourMinuteSecond
```

You could check the result by executing the following query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '8:08:8 PM'), 108) AS HourMinuteSecond
```

If you don't want 24 hours format, you could use

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, <your column name>, 131), 14)), 11), ':000', ' ') AS HourMinuteSecond
```

Example:

```
   SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '8:8:8 PM'), 131), 14)), 11), ':000', ' ') AS HourMinuteSecond
```

Comment: i dont want it in 24hr format. for 08PM also it should show, 08:00:00 PM and not 20:00:00

Comment: But it is adding one more 0 when it is 12PM...it should show 12:00:00 PM and not 012:00:00 PM. Could you please help me out with that, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've checked, it work on SQL Server 2014: http://rextester.com/DDV71112. Maybe there is difference in SQL Server 2008. You could try to reduce  amount of cutted characters, currently 14, to check if it's working.

Comment: yeah, but when I try to pull the data in SSRS Reporting tool, it adds 0 to it. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Ok, I got the problem, the table from which I am pulling the datetime has length of 12 for either cases, i.e, when it 8:00:00 AM or 18:00:00 PM due to additional spaces. Could you please help me out with giving a fix for this so that either of the cases have same length.

Comment: the additional spaces are before the hour...example.. '  8:02:24 AM' and ' 12:17:59 PM'

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand the problem. Could you create a demo for your problem on rextester.com?

Comment: declare @d varchar(20)
set @d=' 12:17:59 PM' --@d='  8:02:24 AM'
--select len(@d)


SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @d, 131), 14)), 14), ':000', ' ') AS HourMinuteSecond

Comment: sorry, I am not able to login in to rextester

Comment: Please change second parameter of RIGHT function to 11. I've updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Below sample code will add 0 based on the hour part length (1 or 2).

```
declare @hour char(2)
    declare @time varchar(20)='8:02:24 PM'
    select @hour=substring(@time,1,charindex(':',@time)-1)
    if len(@hour)=1
    begin
       set @hour='0'+@hour
       set @time=@hour+substring(@time,charindex(':',@time),10)
    end   
    select @time
```