# Converting "Time" Datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Mangement Studio. I have a column name "StartTime". The datatype of this column is "Time".
The values of "StartTime" is:

```
20:30:00.0000000
```

However, I want to change the format to 08:30 PM

This is my following SQL command:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),[StartTime],100) from hello
```

The result will be 8:30 PM which is not I want. What i want is 08:30 PM

Comment: Question is not clear, Can you please update. Didn't understand well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Microsoft SQL Server Mangement Studio

Comment: @JestinSebastian I have edited my post to make it clearer

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179645/convert-time-in-hhmmss-ampm-format-sql)

Comment: It's generally best to format data for presentation purposes in the application rather than T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited query**

This should work for you.

```
SELECT STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VarChar(7), [StartTime], 0), 7), 6, 0, ' ')
```

As you can see in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles) there are plenty of time styles

Comment: This only works when the time has the format hh:mm. A time often have seconds and miliseconds. If the time has seconds and/or miliseconds - this will give an incorrect format

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you absolutely right, initial time format could be anything, but i hope my example could clarify things a little.

Answer (score 1):

This should give the format described

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+STUFF(CONVERT(char(6),[StartTime],100),5,0,' '),8)
```